# How do I create a generator within a generator- Python

Tags: python, generator

If I created a list:

```
_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

and tried to get every value `<=` 6 by using a generator:

```
test = next(i for i in a for a in _list if i <= 6)
```

(btw this doesn't work ↑↑↑↑↑)

How do I iterate through lists within a list using a generator? If this is not possible, what method can I use in place of this?

I have looked here:
[python generator of generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033401/python-generator-of-generators), but could not find an answer...

Comment: Why don't you use a list comprehension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `chain` from builtin module `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain

_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(list(i for i in chain.from_iterable(_list) if i <= 6))
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

What `itertools.chain` does? According [manual pages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
>   it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the
>   iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a
>   single sequence.

Comment: If I wanted to find the index of each output, how would I do that?

Comment: @flameboi You can index resulting list: `list(i for i in chain.from_iterable(_list) if i <= 6)[0]` for example.

Comment: @ Andrej What does that mean? I don't understand.

Comment: To clarify, in my first comment, I was asking if there was a way to output `[0][0]` for `1` for example.

Comment: @flameboi Do you mean `print(_list[0][0])`?

Comment: kind of... i want to use a function that will output `_list[0][0]` if I input `[1]`

Comment: @flameboi Consider to make another question then.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, but thanks for your consideration. If you interested, I did `for x in _list: try: print(x.index(test)) except ValueError: quit()`

Answer (score 2):

in that case, you don't need to create a generator of generator. Just create a double for loop in one generator (to flatten the list, then test for the element values):

```
_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

gen = (x for sublist in _list for x in sublist if x <= 6)
```

this double `for` comprehension syntax needs some using to, comprehensions are generally written "the other way round", but not in the case of loops, hence your confusion. A more general form would be:

```
(expression(item) for sublist in input_list for item in sublist if condition(item))
```

then to get the first matching element:

```
print(next(gen,None))  # None is printed if there's no matching element
```

(to get all the elements, of course you have to iterate on `gen`, `next` provides the "next" values, like if you're iterating "manually" on your generator)

Answer (score 0):

to nest two fors in the same generator you must reverse the order

```
test = next(i for a in _list for i in a if i <= 6)
```

Comment: When I print `test`, it outputs `1`. Shouldn't it output `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`?

Comment: @flameboi `next()` gets only the next element. If you want all elements use `list()` to fully consume the generator: `test = list(i for a in _list for i in a if i <= 6)` (at that point you can use a list comprehension instead, that always returns a list)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `itertools.takewhile` and `itertools.chain` to create an iterator matching your requirements

```
>>> from itertools import chain, takewhile
>>> itr = takewhile(lambda i: i<=6, chain(*_list))
>>> print (list(itr))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> t = (i for a in _list for i in a if i <= 6)
>>> next(t)
1
>>> next(t)
2
>>> next(t)
3
>>> next(t)
4
>>> next(t)
5
>>>
```

Use `list` to convert the iterator to a list

```
>>> t = (i for a in _list for i in a if i <= 6)
>>> list(t)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```